# What is the best possible way to read data from a URL using php and Symfony2 framework?

Tags: php, parsing, url, symfony

I building a project using symfony2 framework. I have to parse a user inputted URL and analyze it. For example if a user inputs a URL like "[http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Galaxy-GT-I9300-Factory-Unlocked/dp/B007VCRRNS/ref=sr_1_1?s=wireless&ie=UTF8&qid=1362207625&sr=1-1&keywords=samsung+galaxy+s3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007VCRRNS)" the program should extract the model name,price,image etc.

Is there any bundles or plugins that i can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use File_get_contents for fetching data, use Javascript for fetching data too as there are many options available:

```
<?php
    $output = file_get_contents(
        'http://www.website.com/');
    $output = str_replace('rhs','"rhs"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('lhs','"lhs"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('error','"error"',$output);
    $output = str_replace('icc','"icc"',$output);

    $json = json_decode($output);
    $rhs = $json->rhs;
?>
```

and Use jQuery ajax

```
jQuery.ajax( url [, settings] )
jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

and pure JavaScript script

```
function parseURLParams(url) {
  var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1;
  var queryEnd   = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1;
  var query      = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1);

  if (query === url || query === "") return;

  var params  = {};
  var nvPairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&");

  for (var i=0; i<nvPairs.length; i++) {
    var nv = nvPairs[i].split("=");
    var n  = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
    var v  = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);
    if ( !(n in params) ) {
      params[n] = [];
    }
    params[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
  }
  return params;
}
```

Use as follows:

```
var urlString = "http://www.foo.com/bar?a=a+a&b%20b=b&c=1&c=2&d#hash";
var urlParams = parseURLParams(urlString);
```

which returns a an object like this:

```
{
  "a"  : ["a a"],     /* param values are always returned as arrays */
  "b b": ["b"],       /* param names can have special chars as well */
  "c"  : ["1", "2"]   /* an URL param can occur multiple times! */
  "d"  : [null]       /* params without values are set to null */ 
}
```

So

```
parseURLParams("www.mints.com?name=something")
```

gives

```
{name: ["something"]}
```

Comment: But i need the URL contents..Not the parameters..Like the page titles,product price(from the amazon page) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Strictly have no idea yet on how to do so, but it could be great to see in symfony code how the current url is analyzed and binded into a Request() object, with all GET and POST parameters extracted.

May be re-usable to analyse inside your services / controllers your urls, and just play with Request object generated with GET params in $request->query.

Just a thought =)